# Why does C# allow properties in interfaces?

Tags: c#, interfaces, properties

In C#, the following code is valid

```
interface I{
    int property{get;set;}
}
```

Which doesn't make any sense to me. This seems to break one of the most important principles of interfaces: lack of state (in other words, no fields). Doesn't the property create an implicit private field? Wouldn't that be really bad for interfaces?

Comment: Is lack of state one of the principles of an interface *implementation*? To me, an interface is a way to define a contract, i.e. if a class implements such interface, then it has all the methods and properties defined in the contract.

Comment: A property is just a get method and a set method. Since interfaces are just a list of methods you have to implement, it's natural that interfaces can have them.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine Certainly the concept of a contract is the most important principle of interfaces, but lack of state is also important. This helps keep it separate from an abstract class. IE in Java 8 this ends up being the only major difference between interfaces and abstract classes.

Comment: @Doval From what I understand a property implicitly creates a private variable under the hood, so its "more" than just a get/set.

Comment: Because its not a field.  See [Why can't C# interfaces contain fields?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2115550/289086)

Comment: @dgrin91 - only for classes.

Comment: @Doval: It is natural that an interface **declares** such methods, but not that it implements them.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

I think the confusing part is that if you write `int Property { get; set; }` inside a class, then it's an auto-property with implicit backing field.

But if you write exactly the same thing in an interface, then *it's not auto-property*, it just declares that the property is part of the interface and that any type that implements the interface has to contain that property (as auto-property or not), but it doesn't create the backing field.

One way to see the difference is to write `int Property { get; }`: this is valid in an interface and declares a property that has only a getter, but no setter. But it won't compile in a class (unless you're using C# 6.0), because auto-property has to have a setter.

Answer (score 22):

Defining the property as you've shown is the same as defining methods `int GetProperty()` and `void SetProperty(int i)`. Properties are powerful short-hand in C#.

A property does not implicitly create a private field in C#. That is the default implementation of an `auto-property`, for example `public string MyString { get; set;}` - however, a property which defines custom logic in the `get` method does not generate an implicit private field.

Lastly, as interfaces are concerned with *public* API, what would it matter if the implementation of an interface property relied on a private field - implicit or otherwise? That is hidden from consumers of the interface regardless.

Comment: Ahh... I didnt realize it only happens for auto-properties, and since you have to override it, that makes sense. But if the interface was to create an internal private variable, implementers would not have access to it - an obvious problem.

Comment: If you define a property in a C# interface, the implementation of that property is left to the implementing class - they can make it an auto-property, or define custom logic as they see fit. No field is added to the *interface*.

Answer (score 16):

Properties **are** methods! A backing field will be added to the class which *implements* the interface (either manually or through an auto-property).

Comment: Sometimes there will be no backing field.  Though it would be rare to define both a get and a set and not have a backing field for it.

Comment: +1 _Properties are methods!_   yes!  I like writing Propertymethods but code-reviewing co-workers don't see it that way and we really miss opportunities for some nice expressive encapsulations in our programs.

Comment: Those "property methods" should be quick though, like no DB lookups or anything. There's an implied contract that property access is fast, Get* methods can be slow.